# How to take selenium webdriver control inside below java script to click on text box

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

Que: How to take selenium webdriver control inside below java script to click on text box

Need to bring the selenium webdriver control with in Java script then click on the text box
click on the text box "input id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in"" and enter value inside that

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <div id="mainBody" class="body main-content" aria-label="(N002A) No customer"  role="complementary" style="padding-top: 50px;">
   <div id="Tabs1" class="Tabs topLevel CoachView tab-content CoachView_show"  data-eventid="" data-viewid="Tabs1" data-config="config14" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.Tabs">
    <div id="Validation_Errors1" class="Validation_Errors topLevel CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Validation_Errors1" data-config="config24" data-bindingtype="ValidationError[]" data-binding="local.validationErrors[]" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_4f1d8c7c_e32f_44e6_97c3_48661f7ae3b9.Validation_Errors"></div>
   <div id="Feedback1" class="Feedback topLevel CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Feedback1" data-config="config18" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.Feedback">
    <div id="Form_Scope1" class="Form_Scope topLevel CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Form_Scope1" data-config="config2" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.Form_Scope">
   <form>
    <div id="div_4_1" class="ContentBox" data-view-managed="false">
   <div id="div_4_1_1" class="Fieldset CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Fieldset1" data-config="config26" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.Fieldset">
   <fieldset>
   <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="div_4_1_1_1" class="ContentBox" data-view-managed="false">
   <div id="div_4_1_1_1_1" class="span6 CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Fieldset_Column1" data-config="config28" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.Fieldset_Column">
 <div id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1" class="ContentBox" data-view-managed="false">
 <div id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_1" class="ListSingle CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="ListSingle1" data-config="config25" data-bindingtype="BpmCustomerSearchScope" data-binding="local.customerRegion" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.ListSingle">
 <div id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2" class="String CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="String1" data-config="config22" data-bindingtype="String" data-binding="local.customerSearchExpression"     data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_335ceb1a_da60_46fc_818c_04701f47d154.String">
 <div class="w-string w-group clearfix">
 <div class="p-label-container span4">
 <div class="p-fields-container span8">
 <input id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in" class="p-field span12" type="text">
 <div class="p-field" style="display: none;"></div>
 <div class="p-help-block"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Note : i have tried below different methods to try.

```
  //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
// driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("mainBody")));
   //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Fill    Quote']")));
 // System.out.println("*****Frame handed*******");
 // driver.findElement(By.id("mainBody")).click();

 // Thread.sleep(30000);
//driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Output : Output :

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.37.0.0
Listening on port 10809
Nov 20, 2013 2:39:37 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Nov 20, 2013 2:39:37 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
****Going for frame handing********
*Focus on main body*****
FAILED: testQTO02
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `<input id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in" class="p-field span12" type="text">` is in any frame. 
If yes use

```
driver.switchTo.frame("frameName");
```

before using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in")).sendKeys("input key");
```

Comment: frame name is not available therefore i'm facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might not have anything to do with the frame issue, but in a coach, the id is auto-generated to represent the position in the DOM, so it will change if you add or move coach views. Using the data-viewid or the label may be more reliable.